# How do print second column elements in row separated by comma(,) if the first element of column is same

Tags: perl

The input what I am handling is as follows.

```
Q9NRG9 15
Q9NRG9 160
Q9NRG9 56
Q9NRG9 89
Q16613 26
Q16613 63
Q16613 102
O95477 19
O95477 91
O95477 78
O95477 86
O95477 16
O95477 203
O95477 66
P78363 18
P78363 159
P78363 88
```

I want output as

```
Q9NRG9 15,160,56,89
Q16613 26,63,102
O95477 78,86,16,203,66
```

I tried with perl program, but I couldn't get correct output what I want.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl` from the command line:

```
perl -lane '
    push @{ $h{$F[0]} }, $F[1] 
}{ 
    $" = ","; 
    print "$_ @{ $h{$_} }" for keys %h
' file
O95477 19,91,78,86,16,203,66
Q9NRG9 15,160,56,89
P78363 18,159,88
Q16613 26,63,102
```

To maintain the order, you can do:

```
perl -lane '
    $k{$F[0]}++ or push @r, $F[0];
    push @{ $h{$F[0]} }, $F[1] 
}{ 
    $" = ","; 
    print "$_ @{ $h{$_} }" for @r
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
open (FILE, "text.txt") or die  "cannot open file".$!;

my %data;
while(<FILE>){
        chomp($_);
        my ($key, $value) = split(/\s+/,$_);
        push(@{$data{$key}}, $value);
}
foreach (keys %data){
   print $_."  ".join(",",@{$data{$_}})."\n";
}
```